# What's the right way to add assets to layout XMLs in CE 1.9 and EE 1.14?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme-fallback, ee-1.14

I want to add another css file in the header on every page. In earlier versions, I would have

1. Copied **app/design/frontend/base/default/layouts/page.xml** to **app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layouts/page.xml**
2. Add my action to the appropriate block in **app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layouts/page.xml**

   ```
   <default translate="label" module="page">
       <label>All Pages</label>
       <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
           <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
               ...
               <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/my_header.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
           </block>
           ...
       </block>
       ...
   </default>
   ```

From what I understand, the theme fallback in 1.9 is supposed to keep you from having to copy from the base .xml files. Following what I found at [Layout updates in theme.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37451/layout-updates-in-theme-xml), I attempted this using the following:

**app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/etc/theme.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>    
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <default_page>
                <file>my_theme/page.xml</file>
            </default_page>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

**app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layout/page.xml:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/my_header.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Doing this kills my theme as well as the RWD theme. What am I missing? I know I could just copy it as in previous versions. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
You will need to change your file `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layout/page.xml` to `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layout/themename.xml` as page is already declared e.g in `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/etc/theme.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>    
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <default_page>
                <file>my_theme/mytheme.xml</file>
            </default_page>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

When magento renders renders it merges all the `layout.xml` files, so if you have the same name such as `page` it will overwrite the other updates. You can read more here: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/digging-deeper-into-magentos-layout-xml-part-2/

Also make sure you don't redeclare the blocks you can just do the following:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/my_header.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. However, doing that still loads a blank page. If I remove my page.xml altogether, I get the page without styling. Nothing is getting logged either. Is there something I need to change in my theme.xml?

Comment: Correction: there was something else going on. Without page.xml, the enterprise styles are still there.

Comment: Just updated my answer.